# How to write index for levi-civita symbol?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I need write (2) on latex, but when i try \epsilon_{\alpha}^{\beta\gamma}, latex shows me (3), somebody knows how to do left that space between index?

Comment: look into the [tensor package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf)

Comment: An alternative to `tensor` is my [tensind](http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/bezos/tensind.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tensor, so why not using the `tensor` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\newcommand{\levicivita}{}% initialize
\def\levicivita#1#{\tensor#1{\epsilon}}

\begin{document}

\[
\levicivita{_{\alpha\beta\gamma}}
\qquad
\levicivita{_{\alpha}^{\beta\gamma}}
\qquad
\levicivita{^{\beta}_{\alpha\gamma}}
\]

\[
\levicivita*{*^{\beta}_{\alpha\gamma}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

Just put a `{}` before `^`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\epsilon_{\alpha}{}^{\beta\gamma}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]